# Python pandas alternative to 'map' for function of 2 variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to put 2 tables into 1, namely corporate announcement date and it's price on that day (on another table)

I have 2 dataframes with the following columns

```
df1: date, announcement, ticker

date        ticker   announcement
25/4/2013   AAPL     Change in Boardroom
25/4/2013   GOOG     OTHERS
25/4/2013   AMZN     Change in Audit Committee

df2: date, ticker, price

date        ticker   announcement
22/3/2012   AAPL     100.00
23/3/2012   AAPL     102.30
24/3/2012   AAPL     105.40
...
...
```

```
def getPrice(dt,tk):
    try:
        return df2[(df2['date']>=dt)&(df2['ticker']==tk)].sort_values(by='date')['price'].values[0]
    except:
        return 0

prices_array = list(map(getPrice,df1['date'].values,df1['ticker'].values))

df1['price'] = prices_array
```

For the "map" function, the whole process takes very long time. I would love to use apply for df, but I only know how to use apply with lambda function which does not contain "if, then".

I want an extra column like this:

```
date        ticker   announcement               price
25/4/2013   AAPL     Change in Boardroom        124.10
25/4/2013   GOOG     OTHERS                     50.85
25/4/2013   AMZN     Change in Audit Committee  102.20
```

Any suggestion on quick ways to do this? Or can do this in a short amount of time?

Thank you and appreciate your help

Comment: Can you share your dummy dataframe and also your expected output? It's easier to understand that way.

Comment: @MohitMotwani have added that, thanks

Comment: Do you want the prices of the earliest date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `'.join'`

```
df.set_index(['date', 'ticker']).join(df2.set_index(['date', 'ticker'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your function for `DataFrame.apply()` with `def` instead of `lambda`. Define it in advance and then put the function name where the lambda would go, same as you did for `map()`.

The applied function gets a `Series` argument, so you can get the whole row.

Comment: can you answer the question instead of a generic one? Thanks